# How to get DNS A record IP directly from Route 53?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I use Route 53 failover to switch to secondary server when primary fails.

I would like to stop processes on primary when secondary is live... I am considering using the IP from Route 53 as the trigger.

How can I get that IP directly from Route 53 to avoid cache delays?

Comment: Route 53 failover will not send requests to the primary target unless the health check passes flags the target as healthy again. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Route53 to see what the authoritative name servers for your domain are. They will appear as an `NS` record. Pick one of them and query it directly. For example if one of the name servers of your domain is `ns1.aws.com` and your A record is `www.example.com` then you could query for the current IP address of your A record using a tool like `nslookup` as so:

`nslookup www.example.com ns1.aws.com`

This will perform a DNS query directly against the authoritative name server for your domain, bypassing any DNS cache.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark... forgot to mention I was using Node (I added a tag). Will try to find a package that implements the features from `nslookup` and try this out.

Comment: @sunknudsen https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_class_dns_resolver you would set the resolver server to the Route53 name server, then call `resolve4()` to get the current IPv4 address of the domain name.

Comment: For getting the `NS` from cli - `aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id %HOSTED_ZONE_ID% --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Type == 'NS']"
`